# How to update python 3.5.2 to 3.5.4?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, python3

I 'm using python 3.5.2 and when I was trying to use DataFrame then I found a bug. A man had sugested me that, that is a bug in version 3.5.2 and he advised me to use version 3.5.4.
I had try to run

`sudo apt-get install python 3.5.4`

but when I run

`python3 --version`

Result is:

`Python 3.5.2`

I 'm using Ubuntu 16.04
Is there any way to upgrade by pip or something else?
Many thanks!

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get install python 3.5.4` threw some errors, right? You should include them in your question… You cannot upgrade Python3 using [default Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3) and unfortunately, even the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial) which usually provides additional versions does not support 3.5.